# Is the claim that Qabil started worshipping fire authentic?

Tags: authenticity

I have seen lots of forums where people claim that Qabil started worshipping fire after Allah (may He be Exalted and Glorified) didn't accept his sacrifice.

 But is this claim authentic?

Comment: Who claims this? Would you mind sharing a source?

Comment: I think I read that from some comments on YouTube. But after I asked this question I did some research and now I answered this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the name of Allah. the Most Merciful, the Most Gracious.

There were historians from the People of the Book (jews and christians) who claimed that Qabil and his sons started worshipping fire. This claim is false because Allah (may He be Exalted and Glorified) says:

[image: كَانَ النَّاسُ أُمَّةً وَاحِدَةً فَبَعَثَ اللَّهُ النَّبِيِّينَ مُبَشِّرِينَ وَمُنذِرِينَ]

> Mankind was [of] one religion [before their deviation]; then Allah sent the prophets as bringers of good tidings and warners

When a Quranic ayah or the Prophet (may peace and blessings of Allah be upon him) say something, there's no debate. It is one million percent true - Allah is the Knower of all things, it is the same for you if you were to to do something secretly in middle of the night or do something openly in daytime, Allah (Pure and Perfect is He) knows it.

Ibn Abbas (may Allah be pleased with him) said:

> “Between Nuh (Noah) and Adam were 10 generations, all of them were upon shariah of the truth, then they differed. So Allah sent prophets as bringers of good news and as warners”
>   
>   *(Tahdheerus-Sajid min Ittikhadhil-Quburi Masajid)*

Ibn Urwah Al-Hanbali (d.837 H) also said:

> “This saying *(of Ibn Abbas (may Allah be pleased with him))* refutes those historians from the People of the Book who claim that Qabil (Cain) and his sons were fire-worshippers.”

And Allah knows best.

Comment: I thought there were Prophets even between Prophet Adam & Prophet Noah.

Comment: Yes there was (such as Idris and Sheath, may peace be upon them). But they only told their people to stay away from sins such as Zina and music, but not shirk.